# Accessing a resource file from a different project with ResourceManager C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-resource

I have a Visual Studio solution consisting of multiple projects. In one of the projects, I have a languagelocalization resource file. I would like to access this file in code in a different project using ResourceManager. Normally when accessing a resource file in the same project I would use:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Namespace.LanguageLocalization", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

However when I use that same code in a different project, it can't find the resource file. I double checked to make sure this project is referenced by the project with the resource file and its declared in a using statement at the top of the class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771130/read-resources-from-a-dll-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771130/read-resources-from-a-dll-file) ?

Comment: This is slightly different and contains code examples which are helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second argument to the `ResourceManager` constructor specifies the assembly that contains the resources. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` won't work because that returns the assembly for your other project. Instead, pass `typeof(APublicClassInTheResourceAssembly).Assembly`; any class in the resource assembly will do.