# Extract resources from dll in c# on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, resources

I have a WP7 application that needs to extract resources from a dll.
I have the DLL binary and a string identifying the resource ("@AppResLib.dll,-100")

How can I extract the resource from the dll?

Comment: Is this a Windows (PC Windows) DLL? If not, how did you create this DLL?

Comment: The way you do it depends on the type of DLL. Is it a managed assembly? Or just a WinAPI DLL? If it is an assembly, you just need to know the namespace of the resources in question (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771130/read-resources-from-a-dll-file?rq=1). If it is not, you can use the WinAPI and pinvoke to get the data. Here is the idea: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FindResource.html