# DLL How do i add sounds?

Tags: vb.net, audio, dll, wav

i came here largely for a question i can't find.
I just found out creating dlls and stuff.
I'm working on a project with a modified extension that helps met programming applications (.xdat). 
So my question is. How do i add a sound file (.wav) to a dll.
i already know how to do it for images.

```
Public Shared imageName as System.Drawing.Image = My.Resources.imageName
```

Comment: Add it to the resources.

Comment: I already did,  but i need to access it from a Windows Application.  Not my dll...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771130/read-resources-from-a-dll-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125698/how-to-play-wav-audio-file-from-resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finally worked! I have found out how to do this.
I'll explain it for the other people wanting to know this. (.WAV only)

```
Public Class Sounds
    '// default sounds \\
    Public Shared Function menuMusic()
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.menuMusic,     AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
        Return True
    End Function
```

And then in the application itself.
Just do

```
ERBAKL.Sounds.Int.menuMusic
```

It will autoplay.
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: A side note, functions are for returning something that you would use. I would recommend just making it a method and calling it.

Comment: Make it `Public Shared Sub` @Rootel